# Finding the times a # is in an array

Tags: c

Hi guys this program makes a function that produces an array of random numbers. It then uses another functions to display how many times the number a user provided is in the list. I'm having trouble in displaying the times a number shows up in the array since the output is always 0.

```
10 32 31 5 34 39 10 15 39 25 26 10 27 21 
50 31 3 21 29 16 12 42 29 30 8 28 19 8 39 1 
19 50 34 2 4 18 40 14 34 30 40 12 41 16 32 42 
48 34 12 28
```

Type a number to see how many times it appears in your list: 16
.Your number is listed 0 times

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int MakeRand()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
}

void fillArray( int arr[], int high)
{
    int i,N;
    N = 50;
    for (i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % high +1;
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}

int CountNumb(int arr[], int x)
{
    int k,j;
    j = 0;
    for (k=0;k<50;++k);
    {
        if (arr[k] == x)
        {
            j = j++;
        }
        return j;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int nums[50];
    int b,k,n;

    MakeRand();
    fillArray(nums,50);
    printf("Type a number to see how many times it appears in your list: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    b = CountNumb(nums,n);
    printf("Your number is listed %d times\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of the `for` statement.

Comment: I took the ";" off and ran it again with no change. Still displaying 0 when a number is in the list.

Comment: That's only the tip of the iceberg in this code. `j = j++;` invokes undefined behavior. You never include `stdlib.h`, which houses the definition of `srand()`. You never include `time.h` which houses the declaration of `time()`. You still have plenty of work ahead of you.

Comment: Also, the `return` statement is inside the loop, so the loop will only check `arr[0]`.

Comment: My "return j;" was in the wrong place here is the updated code:int CountNumb(int arr[], int x)
  {
   int k,j;
   j = 0;
   for (k=0;k<50;++k)
    {
     if (arr[k] == x)
      {
       j = j+1;
      }
    }
    return j;
  }

Answer (score 3):

There are three issues in your `CountNumb` functions:

1. There is an unnecessary semicolon after your `for` loop stament.
2. You need to do `j++`, instead of `j = j++;`. You cannot do `j = j++;` as it leads to `undefined behavior`.
3. You are returning inside the `for` loop instead of returning after completing the `for` loop.

---

```
int CountNumb(int arr[], int x)
{
    int k,j;
    j = 0;
    /* for (k=0;k<50;++k); */ /* Isuee 1 here, trailing semicolon */
    for (k=0;k<50;++k)
    {
        if (arr[k] == x) {
            /* j = j++; */ /* Issue 2 here, you just need j++ */
            j++;           /* Or j = j + 1;, or j += 1; but NOT j = j++ */
        }
       /*  return j; */ /* Issue 3 here, you need to return at end of function */
                        /* Not inside the for loop */
    }
    return j;
}
```

Also you need to `include<stdlib.h>`, and `include<time.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from adding `stdlib.h` and `time.h` and fixing that lost semicolon, you should have placed your return statement in `CountNumb()` outside the for loop.

Change your CountNumb as follows:

```
int CountNumb(int arr[], int x)
  {
   int k,j;
   j = 0;
   for (k=0;k<50;++k)
    {
     if (arr[k] == x)
      {
       j++;
      }
    }
     return j;
  }
```

The entire code can be found here: [codingground](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcUNaOVNCWnYtdHM)